# New event log nowhere to be found after creating in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-event-log, eventviewer, eventcreate

Through PowerShell, I am attempting to create a new event log and write a test entry to it, but it is not showing up the Event Viewer. This is the command I'm using to create a new event log:

`new-eventlog -logname TestLog -source TestLog`

And to write a new event to it:

`write-eventlog TestLog -source TestLog -eventid 12345 -message "Test message"`

After running the first command, there is no "TestLog" log in the event viewer anywhere, and I would expect it to show up in the Applications and Services Logs section. After running the second command, same result. However, I *am* seeing a registry key for the log at HKLM\SYSTEM\services\eventlog\TestLog. Just not seeing anything in the event viewer.

So, 2 questions: When *should* I be seeing the event log? After it gets created or after I write the first event to it? And, more importantly, why am I not seeing it at all?

I'm using Windows Server 2008R2, and am logged in and running the PS as an administrator.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you refreshing the `eventvwr.msc` after this? I copied/pasted your commands and it worked as expected.  Right-click the "Applications and Services Logs" container and select "Refresh".

Comment: Yes, I have refreshed many times. There has to be something I'm missing...

Comment: @MegaMatt - are you running Powershell as an admin when creating the event source? I've had a lot of silent powershell failures without doing so.

Comment: Yes, running as an admin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Terrible reason: I needed to close the Event Viewer and re-open. That's completely insane. Thanks for help.

Comment: Odd, I guess your refresh was misbehaving. :) Glad you resolved this, please be sure [to accept your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.

Comment: I will second the "refresh" not being sufficient when creating a new log. Reload the viewer.

Comment: Same issue. Had to restart computer for it to show! nothing else worked including restart Event Viewer.